# NInject InRequestScope does not return the same instance for MVC4

Tags: ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I have installed ninject throught nuget so I have the following:

```
public static void Start() 
{
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));          
    bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
}
```

in `NinjectWebCommon` in the app_start folder.

In the registration I've added some to be `InRequestScope`, but it doesn't seem to work. When I put a breakpoint right after the registration and try to do a `Kernel.Get<T>()` the constructor will be executed every time, and the constructor will also be executed every time an instance is requested during the request. Is this a known issue in MVC4? Or should it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works within a request only. The startup code is not within a http request.

Comment: Thank you. Then it have to be something else that is wrong with my code. I had a second look at it and you are absolutely right.